# What would happen if gamma-ray burst from a supernova burst hit the sun?

Tags: sun, estimation, gamma-rays, supernova, order-of-magnitude

What would happen if gamma-ray burst from a supernova burst hit the sun? Would the sun explode? Would the sun expand. Have a longer lifetime? Shorter Lifetime? Because people are nit-picky about stuff like this, we'll say it is about 200 light years away (Yeh I just watched this on Vsauce what is the brightest thing in our universe).

Can you answer progressively- in the first 3 seconds, in the next 5 seconds, long term etc

Comment: How did GRB130427A _not_ hit the Sun? What do you mean by "gamma-ray burst" if not a burst of gamma rays? And, what would it mean for that whatever-it-is to "hit" the Sun?

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: OK, so, what makes you think that GRB130427A did _not_ hit the Sun?

Comment: Sorry it seems as though I had made a mistake. I did not know that GRB is an already occurring gamma ray burst. I thought it was a star that will supernova with a GRB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gamma ray bursts hit the sun all the time. The Earth too. Otherwise, how would we know about them?

You really mean "...a nearby..." GRB. Well that all depends on how close, or more specifically, how much energy.

Generally, however, GRBs are short events, with "long" being 2 seconds. That means you'll have effects that are mostly on one side, because there isn't time to rotate much.

Due to the optical depth and size of the sun, mostly confined to the very outer layers. There would definitely be some blowoff on the side facing the GRB, and the question of how much is simply a factor of the total energy deposited.

Comment: if a powerful burst did hit the sun, it would probably hit us too, no? in which case the consequences might be dire enough that we wouldn't be around long enough to ponder them...

Comment: That is only if we assume that it was the centre of the burst that hit the sun and not an outer edge...

Comment: People question what if the earth got hit by a GRB so why should this be any different?

Comment: I also made a false assumption. You may want to edit your answer according to my edits

Comment: What is blow-off?

Comment: Blow-off is basically boiling so rapidly that you explode. It's an important mechanism in hydrogen bombs; the x-rays from the small "primary" plutonium bomb blow-off the outer layers of a "pusher" material. It rockets off so quickly that the interior of the fusion side of the bomb is compressed into a tiny point.